# Unlocking moto g power bootloader

Tags: bootloader

I have a `moto g power (2021)` Running `Android 11` and I am searching For a way to unlock the boot loader. When I go to the Motorola website and Follow the steps to unlock it The website tells me that the phone is not eligible for unlocking. Is there a piece of custom software I could install to force unlock the bootloader? Or am I just missing something?

(PS. I am new to all of this so please correct me if I have done anything wrong)

Comment: Nope... if you can't unlock it using the Motorola Bootloader Unlock website, it can't be unlocked.

Comment: "*Or am I just missing something?*" while I don't know the progress for this specific model, I guess what you're missing is that not all Android devices can be unlocked, whether easily or at all...